# Qusetion about Django. my client wants to add additional choices just by the clicking or something. Can i solve this?

Tags: django, choicefield

In my project, there are many choice fields and I used the code like below :

——————————————————models.py——————————————————

AAA_CHOICES = (
 ('choice1', 'choice1'),
 ('choice2', 'choice2')
)

choice_att = models.Choicefield( … choices = AAA_CHOICES)

————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

but my client wants to add additional choices in AAA_CHOICES just by the clicking or something by himself (not by the hardcoding)

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Make another Choicetable and give foreign key relation from your table

Comment: @SarojRai problem was solved by your solution. thank you for your advice
!